# Nested child modification

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on this dynamic form to create multiple nested child form, just like in ryan bates railscast, but i want to specify the amount of nested child before input:

Here's the for controller in ryan's railscast :

> def new
>
> ```
>    @invoice = Invoice.new
>
> 5.times { @invoice.items.build }
> ```
>
> end

So i'm wondering if i can change nested child to dynamicly multiply based from an input form:

I've tried this code below, but it didn't work:

> def new
>
> ```
>    count = params[:item_counts] ---> the value from a text_field_tag
>
>    count.times { @invoice.items.build }
> ```
>
> end

Here's the view:

```
<div id="invoice">
     <%= form_tag invoices_path, :method => "get" do %>
          <%= label_tag :items, "Item amounts :" %><%= text_field_tag :item_counts %><br /><br />
          <%= link_to 'Create New Invoice', new_invoice_path(invoice) %>
     <% end %>
</div>
```

How to pass the value from :item_counts in the text_field_tag to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by passing the value to the controller ? If you submit the form, all your params ( including `params[:item_counts]` ) will be passed to `invoices#create`, i.e. create action of invoices controller.
What exactly is the params passed to the posted `new` method ?

Comment: My question have been solved in [Railsforum](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=47896), thank you for your attention Prasvin